# Ajax/Javascript - File Download

Tags: javascript, ajax

1. Client (Request through XMLHttpRequest) -> Server.
2. Server [Builds CSV and prints it on the output stream of response] -> Client.

Now step 3 should be-> Client's browser should show a download dialogue (save, open and cancel). Since the content type is plain text from the server, and the content disposition is not set, can we create a file using javascript and prompt the user to download?

I know this question is slight stupid. But there is no other option. I have to do it this way.

Changing in the server side script will make it a one minute task. But I have to do it in the client side. The responseText property of the XMLHttpRequest object will be plain text and I have to show download prompt for the text file.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Not that I'm aware of. But you could just use `location.href` (or a form, if POST data is needed) to request the server-side file. With the correct headers (`Content-Disposition: attachment` and I think there's another one) you can have the response be downloaded rather than displayed.

EDIT: Even better, use an `iframe` that's hidden. That way, you can still do a fancy "Loading, please wait" thing in the main page.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically it could be possible, by using Data URI's

```
<a download = "yourfile.csv" href="data:application/octet-stream;charset=YOURCHARSET;base64,BASE64allthedata">Generate</a>
```

Comment: Sir is it actually implemented in HTML 5 and not in lower versions ?
(I mean download attribute of <a>). Thanks for the reply.